# Simulation with Veins_inet example of Veins framework, Omnet++

Tags: networking, omnet++, veins, inet

I'm simulating a scenerio with veins_inet example. I'm using my own map which has 1000 vehicles in it. When i simulate it, it works perfectly fine but there is absolutely no packet exchange after 18 nodes. Even if the simulation time is 500 seconds.Almost 450 above vehicles enter the simulation but don't exchange any packet.

I then tried with the default map square.rou.xml. Just increased the number of vehicles. It behaves in the same manner i.e doesn't work after 18 nodes. I'm stuck here... please help!

Comment: Are you using the "VeinsInetSampleApplication" or an own logic?

Comment: I'm using my exact example.. just copied the related files into my project and running.

Comment: You might want to have a look to the source code. The predefined time, when a vehicle is transmitting a first packet, it set to 20s

Comment: well... i think something like that Host[0] should stop after 20 seconds.

Comment: what changes should i do in that?? the code says that host should stop at 20 sec and continue at 30 seconds. but transmission only takes place at 20 secs and then nothing happens till 500 seconds

Comment: Correct, so in case you like to have more events (in terms of transmissions), you need to change the existing source code. On a high level, ```sendPacket(std::move(packet));``` is what you need

Comment: I need to have random event until the end of simulation maybe... Like for 1 second is too less to observe a network. Then what do you suggest?? It has the move packet command in process message function... Would it help to alter the timings??

Comment: Can you also answer this question plz?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349010/veins-with-aodv-doesnt-work-for-higher-number-of-nodes?noredirect=1#comment124355897_70349010

Comment: You maybe want to start with the OMNeT++ TicToc tutorial. It shows you everything you need to know to influence a simulation. An easy way for your problem seems to be a periodic self-message that sends a packet

Comment: So i have implemented this AODV scenario with veins.. but the problem is that no NODE is replying to the RREQ. I'm using UdpBasicApp. Can you tell me what could be the possible reasons?