# VEINS with AODV doesn't work for higher number of Nodes

Tags: networking, omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I'm using this git repository which has implemented AODV protocol in veins_inet example by including some changes. (VANETTutorials/simulations/routing)
https://github.com/chaotictoejam/VANETTutorials   (it is quiet popular i guess)
However, i need to simulate for higher number of nodes like 1000 around. When i increase the number of nodes in the map. It always shows a constant error. No matter what number of nodes do i code in.

L3AddressResolver:module node[*] not found -- in module (inet::UdpBasicApp) RoutingScenario.node[26].app[0](id=1633, at t=27.1s, event#805654

It always get stuck at same node 26, i.e it doesn't work for more than 15 nodes. IN my custom map, the error occurs at node [129].

Also, No nodes respond to the RREQ and send RREP. (I think no reception is taking place)..

I am using omnet6.0 pre 14
Inetmanet 4.x
veins 5.2

```
[General]
network = RoutingScenario
sim-time-limit = 60s
debug-on-errors = true
cmdenv-express-mode = true
image-path = ../../../../images

# UDPBasicApp
*.node[*].numApps = 1
*.node[*].app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.node[*].app[0].interface = "wlan0"
*.node[*].app[0].destAddresses = "node[*]"
*.node[*].app[0].multicastInterface = "wlan0"
*.node[*].app[0].joinLocalMulticastGroups = true
*.node[*].app[0].localPort = 9001
*.node[*].app[0].destPort = 9001
*.node[*].app[0].messageLength = 100B
*.node[*].app[0].startTime = uniform(1s, 10s)
*.node[*].app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)


# Ieee80211Interface
*.node[*].wlan[0].opMode = "p"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.typename = "Ieee80211DimensionalRadio"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5.9 GHz"
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 3
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 20mW
*.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 10 MHz
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.typename = "AttachedMobility"
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.mobilityModule = "^.^.^.^.mobility"
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.offsetX = -2.5m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.offsetZ = 1.5m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxX = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxY = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
*.node[*].wlan[*].radio.antenna.mobility.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

# HostAutoConfigurator
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.typename = "HostAutoConfigurator"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.interfaces = "wlan0"
*.node[*].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"

# VeinsInetMobility
*.node[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"

# VeinsInetManager
*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
*.manager.host = "localhost"
*.manager.port = 9999
*.manager.autoShutdown = true
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("square.launchd.xml")
*.manager.moduleType = "vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetRoutingCar"

## PhysicalEnvironment
#*.physicalEnvironment.config = xmldoc("obstacles.xml")
#*.radioMedium.obstacleLoss.typename = "IdealObstacleLoss"

# Misc
**.vector-recording = true

# Routing
**.router = "Aodv"
```

```
package vanettutorials.simulations.veins_aodv;

import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium;
import vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetRoutingCar;
import vanettutorials.veins_inet.VeinsInetManager;

network RoutingScenario
{      

        submodules:
        radioMedium: Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium;
        manager: VeinsInetManager;
        node[0]: VeinsInetRoutingCar;

}
```

```
package vanettutorials.veins_inet;

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.HostAutoConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.applications.contract.IApp;

//
// Wireless-enabled Host
//
module VeinsInetRoutingCar extends AdhocHost
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=device/cellphone");
        string router;
        
    submodules:
        routing: <router> like IApp {
            @display("p=558,307");
        }

    connections allowunconnected:
        routing.socketOut --> at.in++;
        routing.socketIn <-- at.out++;
}
```

Comment: is there a max TTL field in route requests?

Comment: Where can i check this?

Comment: well.. i have checked the TTL field. nothing happens by varying it!

Comment: @thardes2 can you answer this too??

Comment: My suggestion is to first try what you are planning to achieve in plain INET and to only then switch to creating/destroying/moving nodes according to a SUMO simulation. Otherwise you will be juggling too many potential sources of errors at the same time.

Comment: My scope of research is vehicular networks... I can't achieve it with only INET??

Comment: @ChristophSommer So i have implemented this AODV scenario with veins.. but the problem is that no NODE is replying to the RREQ. I'm using UdpBasicApp. Can you tell me what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Does your envisioned system already work using only modules from the INET Framework? If not, I suggest you start building a simulation using only the INET Framework, then making nodes move, and only then making nodes move like vehicles

Comment: @ChristophSommer i have tried checking the AODV example with some changes. And it works completely fine. Even with mobilities. (not vehicular). But it's using PingApp (udp). How is it different than udpbasic??

Comment: And i also tested the aodv example section with high speed mobility that uses AODVNetwork. The behaviour is same... only RREQs from the node. and no further stages.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong... the AODV network alone works fine with mobile nodes. Also checked the RSU example of veins.. it works fine too!!